# C# - How can I make one array of different classes that share common properties?

Tags: c#, .net, arrays, generics

I have a C# class called PersonActivity.  This holds a unique Id (int), a PersonId (int), and an ActivityType (string).

I have another class HighlightedActivity that inherits from PersonActivity.  What I need to do is make an array HighlightedActivity[] called "activities", which I've done.  My question is how can I make this one array, but with certain additional properties based on the ActivityType?

My intention is to loop through "activities" of HighlightedActivity type, then set additional properties that are based on the ActivityType.  Activity Types are things like Books that have an ISBN number, while Journals have a Volume and Issue number, and Grants have an Amount.  They all have Id, PersonId, and ActivityType from the PersonActivity class.  I'm not sure what HighlightedActivity class should look like so that I can put all these items in the same list.

Array "activities" should look like:

[0] {Id = 2, PersonId = 5, ActivityType = "Book", ISBN = "13239382"}

[1] {Id = 3, PersonId = 5, ActivityType = "Journal", Volume = 5, Issue = 124}

[2] {Id = 4, PersonId = 5, ActivityType = "Journal", Volume = 8, Issue = 201}

[3] {Id = 5, PersonId = 5, ActivityType = "Journal", Volume = 8, Issue = 202}

[4] {Id = 6, PersonId = 5, ActivityType = "Grant", Amount = 444.00}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create a base activity class and inherit your other objects from that. The base class will have an activity type which can be used to track the type of activity.

Define this as an enum:

```
public enum ActivityType
{
    Book,
    Journal,
    Grant
}
```

Your base class will hold the common properties. It will also have constructors to create derived classes by activity type and from an array. Since we will have an array based constructor, we will validate the array length and add protected members that can be used to convert array objects to their correct types.

```
public abstract class Activity
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public int PersonId { get; set; }
    public ActivityType ActivityType { get; private set; } // consider to use enum

    public Activity(ActivityType activityType)
    {
        ActivityType = activityType;
    }
    public Activity(object[] values)
    {
        if (values.Length < 4)
            throw new ArgumentException();

        this.Id = getInt(values[0]);
        this.PersonId = getInt(values[1]);
        this.ActivityType = getActivityType(values[2]);
    }
    protected int getInt(object value)
    {
        if (!(value is int))
        {
            throw new ArgumentException();
        }
        return (int)value;
    }
    protected string getString(object value)
    {
        if (!(value is string))
        {
            throw new ArgumentException();
        }
        return (string)value;
    }
    protected decimal getDecimal(object value)
    {
        if (!(value is decimal))
        {
            throw new ArgumentException();
        }
        return (decimal)value;
    }
    protected ActivityType getActivityType(object value)
    {
        ActivityType result;
        if(value is string)
        {
            if (!Enum.TryParse((string)value, out result))
            {
                throw new ArgumentException();
            }
        }
        else if(value is ActivityType)
        {
            result = (ActivityType)value;
        }
        else
        {
            throw new ArgumentException();
        }
        return result;
    }
}
```

We now define the derived classes which will call base constructors to set base properties as needed. For the array constructors, validate the array length and use base methods to covert array objects to there correct types.

```
public class Book : Activity
{
    public Book() : base(ActivityType.Book) { }
    public Book(object[] values) : base(values)
    {
        if (values.Length != 4) throw new ArgumentException();
        this.ISBN = getString(values[3]);
    }
    public string ISBN { get; set; }
}

public class Journal : Activity
{
    public Journal() : base(ActivityType.Journal) { }
    public Journal(object[] values) : base(values)
    {
        if (values.Length != 5) throw new ArgumentException();
        this.Volume = getInt(values[3]);
        this.Issue = getInt(values[4]);
    }

    public int Volume { get; set; }
    public int Issue { get; set; }
}

public class Grant : Activity
{
    public Grant() : base(ActivityType.Grant) { }
    public Grant(object[] values) : base(values)
    {
        if (values.Length != 4) throw new ArgumentException();
        this.Volume = getDecimal(values[3]);
    }
    public decimal Volume { get; set; }

}
```

Finally, we will create a class that uses the factory pattern to create activities from an array or a list of activities from an array of arrays. The factory will also have a method to test the data you defined above.

```
public class ActivityFactory
{
    public static List<Activity> GetActivities(object[][] values)
    {
        List<Activity> result = new List<Activity>();
        for (int i = 0; i < values.Length; i++)
        {
            result.Add(MakeActivity(values[i]));
        }
        return result;
    }
    static Activity MakeActivity(object[] values)
    {
        Activity result = null;
        switch (values[2].ToString())
        {
            case "Book":
                result = new Book(values);
                break;
            case "Journal":
                result = new Journal(values);
                break;
            case "Grant":
                result = new Grant(values);
                break;
            default:
                throw new ArgumentException("Invalid activity " + values[2].ToString());

        }
        return result;
    }
    public static void RunTest()
    {
        object[][] values = new object[][] {
           new object[] { 2, 5, "Book", "13239382"},
           new object[] { 3, 5, "Journal", 5, 124},
           new object[] { 4, 5, "Journal", 8, 201},
           new object[] { 5, 5, "Journal", 8, 202},
           new object[] { 6, 5, "Grant", 444.00m}
       };
        List<Activity> activities = GetActivities(values);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for this!  It looks like what I need.  Here, I'm looping through them and assigning properties based on the type. I think I may even be able to get ride of some of the code as I won't have the custom values per ActivityType upfront.
 https://dotnetfiddle.net/dXmwwK

Comment: Your welcome. Your issue is a common use case in .net and the Factory Pattern is a good way to handle such use cases while keeping your logic clean. You can mark the answer as accepted so others reading it know it helped you.

Answer (score 3):

You can create base activity class (consider also to make activities read-only Value objects if you are not going to change them after creation):

```
public abstract class Activity
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public int PersonId { get; set; }
    public string ActivityType { get; private set; } // consider to use enum

    public Activity(string activityType)
    {
        ActivityType = activityType;
    }
}
```

And then create custom activity classes which inherit this base class:

```
public class Book : Activity
{
    public Book() : base("Book") { }

    public string ISBN { get; set; }
}

public class Journal : Activity
{
    public Journal() : base("Journal") { }

    public int Volume { get; set; }
    public int Issue { get; set; }
}
```

And keep list of base type activities:

```
var activities = new List<Activity> {
   new Book { Id = 2, PersonId = 5, ISBN = "13239382" },
   new Journal { Id = 3, PersonId = 5, Volume = 5, Issue = 124 },
   new Journal { Id = 4, PersonId = 5, Volume = 8, Issue = 201 },
   new Journal { Id = 5, PersonId = 5, Volume = 8, Issue = 202 }
   // etc
};
```

Then you can cast each activity to appropriate type and retrieve its properties (sample with C# 7 pattern matching):

```
foreach(var activity in activities)
{
    switch(activity)
    {
       case Book book:
           /* use book here */
           break;
       case Journal journal:
           /* use journal here */ 
           break;
       default:
           /* handle unknown activity */
           break;
    }
}
```

You can also switch by activity type and cast activity to appropriate class.

Comment: Thank you!  I didn't realize I could declare an array of Activity like that.  This looks like what I need :)